# According to the specified text mode to find sth

Tags: shell

I have same log file, like this:

```
2016-04-01 11:16:30.745:[11878][TEST][test]
2016-04-01 11:16:30.745:[11878][TEST][wait|hold|name(0x03154246) 101ms]
....
```

at first, I use `grep wait` to found the log

```
2016-04-01 11:16:30.745:[11878][TEST][wait|hold|name(0x03154246) 101ms]
```

then, how can i get the field value

```
value1: 2016-04-01 11:16:30.745
value2: 0x03154246
value3: 101
```

Comment: what is the pattern here? and what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out from what you wrote but something like may be suitable for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

string=$(grep wait "$1")

value1=$(echo "$string" | rev | cut -d ":" -f 2-  | rev)
value2=$(echo "$string" | grep -o -E "\(0x.+\)" | sed 's,),,' | sed 's,(,,')
value3=$(echo "$string" | grep -o -E "[0-9]+ms]$" | sed 's,ms],,')

echo vaule1: "$value1"
echo vaule2: "$value2"
echo vaule3: "$value3"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./get.sh LOG
```

`value1` is everything up to last `:`.

`value2` are digits between last `(0x` and `)`.

`value3` are digits before `ms]` at the end of the string.